# Request for product data not returning anything in sandbox environment

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, in-app-purchase

I have used phonegap for in app purchase, it was working fine but now it is not returning anything after

```
Getting Product Data
```

and when i try to do iap i'm getting the following response

```
plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.updatedTransactionCallback.apply(plugins.inAppPurchaseManager, ["PaymentTransactionStateFailed",0,"Cannot connect to iTunes Store","","",""])
```

i haven't made any changes in the code but not sure what could be the problem...any help?

Comment: Not sure if this is the same problem -- but I've just seen a post on the Apple Developer Forums today from someone who says that the sandbox hasn't been working properly for them since yesterday, when their code previously had no problems.

Comment: say you submit a new version with some new IAP items to Apple.

as you know, the sandbox works fine while that new version is in the waiting cue for a week. when you request product data (sandbox) during that period, it works fine

However:

Rather bizarrely -- JUST while it is in review (ie, for 6 hours or so) -- you WILL NOT be able to request product date (sandbox) - it just won't work.